# Why does Convolutional network need multiple feature maps?

Tags: deep-learning

I am a beginner of deep learning. For convolutional networks such as lenet-5, there are 6 feature maps in the C1 layer. Each feature map is associated with a unique convolution kernel (5x5 matrix).

What is the difference between any 2 feature maps in the same layer? For a black-white image dataset like MNIST (without RGB), people still use 6 feature maps.

I guess, initially, the 6 convolution kernels are randomly generated 5x5 matrices. Therefore, when the same input image is projected to different feature maps, the output of feature maps will be different. And this is the main motivation, right?

Answer (score 2):

Every filter in your convolutional layer extracts a specific feature from the input. One filter could be sensitive to horizontal edges while another is sensitive to vertical edges. A third filter may be sensitive to a triangular shape. You want the feature maps to be as different from each other as possible to avoid redundancy. Avoiding redundancy improves the network's capacity to as many variations in the data as possible.
Random initialization prevents learning duplicate filters.

Why 6 feature maps? This is a result of trying out other numbers of filters. Keep in mind that increasing the number of filters results in higher computational overhead and possibly overfitting (memorizing the training data but not good at classifying new images correctly). Another intuition for 6 is that there's not that much variation in pixels, you'll eventually extract more complex features in subsequent layers. 6 feature maps for C1 ended up working well for the MNIST dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have some example codes to read. But I did not find any explicit definition of "vertical" or "horizontal" edges. So I guess "different filters for different edge directions" was an idea on a much higher level for the guidance purpose. When it comes to the coding or implementation,  especially for MNIST, however, people just put 6 feature maps here without considering the meaning of each feature maps (i.e. vertical, horizontal,etc.) and simply use random initialization to make them different. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Why redundant feature maps are considered "bad"?